# Making copy of one server to another

Tags: networking, virtualization, linux-kvm, hypervisor, linux-server

I have three identical hardware machine. I want to install and configure the centos server on all machines. I need to have exactly the same configuration.

Do I need a hypervisor to create a replica system [clone server] in this scenario?

What does hypervisor here? Can I use the KVM hypervisor for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to deploy CentOS on a identical hardware machine, you don't require Hypervisor. In your requirement, you need to just clone the HDD ( identical ), and you can use clonezilla like diskimage or cloning program.

Hypervisor is something different, where you can install multiple operating systems on a single hardware, wherein operating systems runs independetanly, and uses shared CPU,Network, and storage on the server.